# Regex to check string for unique characters and prohibited characters

Tags: regex, validation

I'm writing a password validation regex and I've managed to get 80-90% of the way there but can't incorporate the last two pieces I need and I'm sick of beating my head against the wall so that's where you guys come in ;)

Here is my expression so far:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{3}).*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E]).*$
```

so in order I have the following rules:

1. `(?!.*(.)\1{3})` - no more than 3 of the same character in sequence
2. `.*(?=.{8,})` - string must be a minimum of 8 characters
3. `(?=.*\d)` - must contain at least one digit
4. `(?=.*[a-z])` - must contain at least one lower case letter
5. `(?=.*[A-Z])` - must contain at least one upper case letter
6. `(?=.\*[\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E])` - must contain at least one of these special characters

I need to add two more restrictions

1) no character other than an alphanumeric or one of my special characters may appear in the string. So I think I have the basic expression correct:

```
^([\w\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E]*)$
```

but when I try to add that into my overall expression it doesn't work or it screws up one of my other conditions, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

2) the string MUST contain 4 unique characters. I cant figure this one out at all.

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: You should use separate checks for each of the requirements. That regex is a monster that cannot easily be maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. (I removed a couple of `.*`s which aren't needed and removed the minimum of 8 chars because that can be incorporated in the final piece.)

```
^
(?!.*(.)\1{3})
(?=.*\d)
(?=.*[a-z])
(?=.*[A-Z])
(?=.*[\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E])
[\w\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E]{8,}
$
```

Also, your last rule:

> the string MUST contain 4 unique characters.

Is already checked for, because you are requesting one digit, one upper, one lower, and one special = four different classes.

Comment: that's why this community is so great, its a 2nd pair of eyes to look at something that you've been staring at for hours in a fresh light, you are absolutely right about the last rule! Here is the expression I went with: ^(?!.*(.)\1{3}).*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E]).*[\w\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?\E]{8,}$

Comment: Unfortunately, your regex doesn't work. It validates `'4mM-~asdfdasf`, `4mM-~'asdfdasf` and `4mM-~ asdfdasf` as a valid passwords. It's because of your errant `.*` hanging around and capturing invalid characters.